# Can multiple form submit id can be same?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

i am having Multiple forms, which contains input tag of type submit , i am using **id=submit** in all the forms

```
    <form  id='geek' method="post" action="#" role="form">

    <input type="text" name="name" class="modal_input" id='name' placeholder="Only Alphabets Allowed" >

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="apply_button text-center center-block" id="submit" />

</form>
```

Second form

```
    <form  id='geek1' method="post" action="#" role="form">

    <input type="text" name="name"  id='name' placeholder="Only Alphabets Allowed" >

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="apply_button text-center center-block" id="submit" />

</form>
```

calling form1

```
 $('#geek').validator();

    $('#geek').on('submit', function (e) {

        ......
    })
});
```

form 2

```
   $('#geek1').validator();

        $('#geek').on('submit', function (e) {

            ......
        })
    });
```

Element IDs should be unique, with this practice am i doing wrong?

Comment: Element IDs should be unique. you have the answer.

Answer (score 4):

> Element IDs should be unique, with this practice am i doing wrong?

Yes, because you're using `id="name"` on more than one `input` element. It's fine to use `name="name"` on more than one element, but it's not fine to use `id="name"` on more than one element.

In terms of your *forms*, `id="geek"` and `id="geek1"` are different IDs, so there's no problem there.

Note that your "form 2" example used `#geek1` in one place and `#geek` in another, which is probably not what you wanted.

Having said that, do you really need `id`s for these forms? How about:

```
$(".common-class-on-the-forms").validator().on("submit", function() {
    // Use `this` here to refer to the specific form that was submitted
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. it helped me, i am  going use unique id . <br />

Comment: can submit button or input  type of submit contains same if we are calling in different form with different id?

Comment: @Jyothilakshmi.R: Can they contain the same **what**?

Comment: I got that id should be unique but  as i said in the form 1 and 2  submit type has same id = submit but its under different form ie.. under different form id. so how should it affect form action? because  form triggers only when it submitted.

Comment: @Jyothilakshmi.R: `id` values must be unique **in the document**, not just within a form. `id` values have essentially nothing to do with forms. The important attribute in forms is primarily `name`.